# Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT not found during compilation, how do I solve?

Tags: java, android, gradle

This morning I woke up with a nasty surprise, my app with over 30k installations was removed from the playstore for no reason. Since I had to fix some things, I took the opportunity to recompile it for the new android versions and I encountered the following problem. In practice, the function that at the first start takes care of requesting permissions, no longer recognizes me "Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT", which is access to the camera (the app works with qr code, so you can understand how important it is ). Could you help me?

```
public void request_permission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, 1);
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(base.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, 1);
    }

}
```

[image]
this is my [build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/Xbta2se8)

I have touched nothing form first version of app, i just have update gradle, targetsdk versione and pressed "run".

Comment: _"CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT", which is access to the camera (the app works with qr code, so you can understand how important it is"_. There's a dedicated `CAMERA` permission, so I'm not sure I understand why you would need `CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT` for scanning QR codes. The `CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT` permission appears to have been removed in API level 29, and even before that it seems like it was intended only for system apps.

Comment: It is an app made for an old version of android. Honestly, I work alone and we talk about things done a long time ago, I don't remember the reason for certain decisions. However, I have always considered this issue of permits and so on as a nuisance, so I have never applied. For safety I will have set everything to "on" and go. I try as you advised me.

Comment: Also, you say that the app was removed for _"no reason"_. While that may have been the case (I have no way of knowing), often when you're in violation of some newly introduced policy you will be notified in some way in the Google Play Developer Console. Then, if you don't fix the issues within a given timeframe, your app could end up getting removed.

Comment: I took it after two years with the fact that my program was sending data for statistical purposes to my server, all obviously specified in the policy (I made some changes trying to be more specific) but it is undeniable that sometimes the google requests are not then so specific. In any case, nothing works anymore.

Comment: Errors came out on errors mainly due to situations of forced incompatibility between android studio, gradle and all the related things. I'm trying to at least be able to compile some more, but as usual, the more unspecific the errors, the happier AndroidStudio is. Now he insists that the main activity no longer exists ... I try to solve it as I can but I'm really rusty with the problem solving above.

Comment: Ok all fixed, now it's work. Compiled and converted to android X and published to playstore. I'm waiting google response. thanks.